# jQuery doesn't support postmessage event?

Tags: jquery, html, postmessage

When I use jQuery event listener to handle message event, like below:

```
$(window).on('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data; // data = undefined
});
```

data is undefined! I'm sure that I have passed data to current window. Because if I use "addEventListener", everything goes well!

So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

jQuery might be preprocessing the event's `data` property, and this operation may not properly support the `message` event (yet).

Try using the `originalEvent` property to fetch your data:

```
$(window).on("message", function(e) {
    var data = e.originalEvent.data;  // Should work.
});
```

Comment: A +1 for you, this just helped me stop pulling my hair out.

Comment: What is the best way to also handle "onmessage" in IE?

Comment: @grim, IE has problems in its support for `postMessage()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#Browser_compatibility and [Is cross-origin postMessage broken in IE10?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16226924/464709).

Comment: +1 - a solution I was looking for.
yet I could not unbind the event using `$(window).off("message")`.
on the other hand, `$(window).bind / $(window).unbind` successfully attached / detached for me a handler to the `message` event.

Answer (score 15):

Some browsers use the "onmessage" event. I suggest a little improvement to the previous answer for increased compatibility:

```
$(window).on("message onmessage", function(e) {
    var data = e.originalEvent.data;
});
```