# How to access parent dom element from child iframe?

Tags: javascript

parent domain is

```
example.com/abc/
```

and the iframe's domain is

```
abcd.example.com/hhh/.
```

is it possible to access the dom element of parent?

Comment: considering you are using iframes, technically they are seperate DOMs

Comment: is there any way to acces the parent dom by using something like postMessage or something else??

Comment: See the following community wiki on this topic will help:
[ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. But only if you have permission to do so. Do you control both domains? If not then, no, this is not possible due to cross domain security restrictions.

Assuming you do have control over both sites you could use window.postMessage to facilitate this communication.

See [this](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe)

Comment: postMessage seems to be [broken in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226924/is-cross-origin-postmessage-broken-in-ie10), I wonder if jQuery has something to deal with that...

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can access it until both are on the same domain.

To access a parent element from iframe u can use javascript at child as follows:

```
parent.document.getElementById('elem');
```

To access any global element :

```
var a=parent.a
```

Comment: The example given is not on the exact same domain.