# IE passes an empty event object with PostMessage

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, postmessage

All versions of IE do this. And all other browser work properly..

My code :

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

Which passes to :

```
  function receiveMessage(event) {
     console.log ( JSON.stringify( event ) ) ;
```

Which, in IE, returns as : `{}`

I `postMessage` with this :

```
var message = { 'origin' : window.location.origin };
var url     = 'https://mywebsite.html';
frames[$(".fancybox-iframe").attr('name')].postMessage(message, url);
```

Again, this works just fine in any other browser. Information passes perfectly. And as far as I can remember, this *used* to work ok in IE.

Comment: What versions of IE are you testing? From what I have read only IE11 supports postMessage while IE8, IE9 and IE10 supports different parts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226924/is-cross-origin-postmessage-broken-in-ie10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not implement `window.location.origin`.  And `JSON.stringify()` is apparently ignoring properties whose value is `undefined` (which its [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) says it will do).

Run this jsFiddle in IE to see: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MP68r/

You can work around the issue by using other properties of `window.location` depending upon exactly what you want to do with that info.

---

You could use this as an alternative:

```
location.href.match(/(^.*?\/\/.*?)[\/$]/)[1].toLowerCase();
```

This will return the part before the first slash in the path which is basically what the origin is.  It is converted to lower case since domain names and protocols are case insensitive so this makes for a canonical comparison.

Comment: Wow huge thanks jfriend00. I'm pretty sure you not only nailed this on the head. Thank you thank you thank you.