# Select frame context with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there a way to programmatically select frame context with Javascript? Let's say there are two different frames present in the current web page, and I need to append 'hello' to the second frame. The problem is that the second frame has a different domain than the current web page. With chrome developer tools, I can simply choose the second frame context and do `$('body').append('hello')` from console, but I should be able to do this programatically.

Reference: [Debugging iframes with Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools)

Is there a way to achieve this?

**intention**: I need to create a bookmarklet that specifically targets the frame that has a different domain than the main webpage.

Comment: related [frame access not possible from dev tools console due to cross-origin restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857289/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same domain is easy:

```
 window.parent.doSomeThing()
```

Cross origin is a little tricky

- [Iframe cross domain JavaScript calls](http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls) from Mads Kristensen is a good article about it.
- David Walsh wrote an article about the html5 option [window.postMessage API](http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage):

> window.postMessage allows for sending data messages between two
> windows/frames across domains

Caniuse.com lists [the browsers already supporting cross-document (postMessage)](http://caniuse.com/#search=cross-document).

Comment: Hi @VDP. Thanks for your help. I am trying to use postMessage, but doing `otherWindow.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);` results in security error because of cross origin. This defies the purpose of using postMessage API in the first place because that's precisely what I need. Do you have any advice?

Comment: My bet is you're using IE < IE11 :( It seems it's a [known issue](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging)... Here's another stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226924/is-cross-origin-postmessage-broken-in-ie10) about it.