# Selecting execution context with use command (Google Devtools)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

I need to use Bookmarklet to change the settings on some sites in its context. I have necessary var, but I dunno with help of which command to change selecting execution context.

[image: Example]

**Which commands do use to change necessary var?**

I checked:

1. [Select frame context with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479117/select-frame-context-with-javascript)
2. [Debugging iframes with Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools)
3. [what is the jQuery / JavaScript context of a frame within an    iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150327/what-is-the-jquery-javascript-context-of-a-frame-within-an-iframe)
4. [Is there a way to change context to iframe in JavaScript    console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console)

But this not help me

Answer (score 3):

hi if you want to select element with id **test2** you can use `document.getElementById('test2')` need to wrap `test2` with quotes

and if element with id **test2** is inside iframe you need to select iframe first and cal `contentDocument`

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id');
iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('test2');
```

or if you are testing with chrome devtools you can change context and use `document.getElementById('test2')` as normal

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But sadly I can't find iframe-id, most likely I misunderstand what I need to do, I'm sorry
[Screenshot](https://i.paste.pics/b81590dfe5466358c09acb1f544b2daf.png),
[also](https://i.paste.pics/315208a51a4020f5d06aecafa5f0f72b.png)

Comment: This migth no longer work [due to cross-origin restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857289/).