# How to access iframe elements from console and avoid permisison denied cross-origin object

Tags: javascript, testing, web-scraping, firefox, console

URL: `www.somewebsite.com`

Inside code there is iframe sources from the same domain:

```
<iframe 
        src="https://abc.somewebsite.com/something/" 
        name="thisiframename"></iframe>
```

I am trying to access inside iframe elements like:

```
window.parent['thisiframename'].document.getElementById("someId")
```

I got such message:

```
SecurityError: Permission denied 
               to access property "document" 
               on cross-origin object
```

Is there any way to bypass this?

## 3rd party edit

Inside dev tools the iframe can be inspected and as soon as the iframe is selected (by inspect element) all nodes in the document can be queried with `document.querySelectorAll("mySelector");` but doing so from the devtools console without a prior insepction of an element fails.

What is needed is to switch the current context from the main document to the document of the relevant iframe.

#### What have i done

Based on my understanding of [HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) or [HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) the following should work

```
var iframeDocument = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1].contentDocument;
// or 
var iframeWindow = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1].contentWindow;
```

But

```
 iframeDocument.title
 // returns Uncaught TypeError: iframeDocument is null
 
 iframeWindow.document.title
 /* throws 
           Uncaught DOMException: 
                                  Permission denied to 
                                  access property "document" 
                                  on cross-origin object
 */
```

Example taken from [iframe (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

[image: mdn Element iframe]

#### What is working

After manually inspecting an element on the page every document query works on the iframe that was selected by inspecting one of its nodes.

[image: after one of the iframe element was inspected it the document can be queried from the console]

#### What should work but is not

Given that the the above is working i would expect that working from the parent frame it should be possible to select any iframe document as well.

But it does not work because the `cross-origin permission` is preventing access

#### What else

There is an open feature request for firefox [Implement JS execution context selector UI](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1605154) to add the setting `devtools.webconsole.input.context`

> feature displays a button on the console's command line that lets you
> change the context in which the expression you enter will be executed

But as far as i can tell from [[meta] JS Execution Context Switching](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1605153) and from [Firefox Developer Tools - Working with iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes) there appears to be no console.meta.command to switch the context to another frame.

#### Question

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Is there a way to switch the `execution.context` from the console?

Comment: Select the iframe as the context for the console evaluation. But what are you actually trying to do with the console?

Comment: I need to make some automation with iMacros. Usually I'm using
`document.getElementById("id");`
but this time it doesn't work. Is there a way to change context by some command, not by clicking it? I need it to work like automation.