# How to create a bookmarklet to display the objects in dataLayer in a seperate window

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet to display some of the objects in the dataLayer and I'm trying to display this data in a separate window.

This:

`for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.length; i++){
    console.log(dataLayer[i]);
}`

can easily display the dataLayer at the console in a raw fashion but that's not what I want.

Can anyone help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data-display page that can accept [MessageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent)s containing the data you want to display:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

        /* for security, check event.origin here and
           return if not a safe/recognized URL */

        console.log(event.data); // prints message as string

        /* dynamically display data on page here */

      }, false);
    </scrip>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- put HTML template for display of data here -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your bookmarklet, open the data-display page in a new window and send it the data using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

```
<!-- bookmarking this link creates the bookmarklet -->
<a href='javascript:(function() {
    var dataWin = window.open("dataDisplayPageUrl.html", "dataWin");
    dataWin.postMessage(dataLayer, "https://mywebsite.com");
})();'>bookmark this</a>
```

**EDIT**: Apparently more complicated in IE: [Is cross-origin postMessage broken in IE10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226924/is-cross-origin-postmessage-broken-in-ie10)

**EDIT 2**: Testing this in Chrome, it appears that there is a small delay between when a new window is opened and when it can receive messages.  Adding a delay to the bookmarklet fixes the problem:

```
<!-- bookmarking this link creates the bookmarklet -->
<a href='javascript:(function() {
    var dataWin = window.open("dataDisplayPageUrl.html", "dataWin");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        dataWin.postMessage(dataLayer, "https://mywebsite.com");
    }, 1000);
})();'>bookmark this</a>
```

Comment: I guess I should have explained better.
Scenario:
- User visits a page,
- Clicks on the Bookmark
- It opens a new window(which will be smaller) and displays all the data from dataLayer.

Comment: Yes, that's what this code does.  If you want the new window to be smaller, you can pass options to window.open.  See docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open