# javascript - window.postmessage - event.data is always null

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, postmessage

I have an iframe and want to send data from the iframe to the parent window.

Inside the js code of the iframe, I have the following statement

```
window.parent.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

The corresponding message handler in the parent window is as follows

```
$(window).bind('message', function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    console.log(event.origin);
    console.log(event.source);
    console.log('received');
});
```

I am loading the code from localhost and the iframe source is also loaded from localhost.
I am running the code in firefox 21.

The problem is that `event.data` is always `null` and `event.orign and event.source` are `undefined`. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
window.parent.postMessage('hello', '*');   
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
       function receiveMessage (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            console.log(event.origin);
            console.log(event.source);
            console.log('received');
        }
```

This will work as intended;
Perhaps there is a problem in event binding("message") with jQuery
Will update when get something on that.

Answer (score 11):

See [Frédéric Hamidi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904539/2985644) for this. What's happened was the jQuery encapsulate the original event in the proper jQuery.event object type.  So, to get the original event you simply need to:

```
$(window).on("message", function(e) {
  console.log("Orignal:", e.originalEvent);
});
```